# list_len is soft-deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I am running some R code and I got the following warning message

```
Warning message:
`list_len()` is soft-deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0.
Please use `new_list()` instead
This warning is displayed once per session.
```

For what it's worth, the calling code looks something like the following

```
  df = convertCallCountsToHashTable(call_counts_hash_table )

  df %>%
    filter(needs_review) %>%
    filter( package != "R_GlobalEnv") %>%
    top_n( num_functions, desc(review_timer ))
```

I know that the code in `convertCallCountsToHashTable` is never directly calling `list_len`; however it does call some methods from `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `lubridate`.

How can I do something like `traceback` to figure out where this warning message is coming from?

How can I make the warning display more than once per session so that I can try to debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `debug` `list_len`, and then use `sys.calls` to see the function stack. Note that since `list_len` isn't exported you have to reference the namespace.

```
my_fun <- function() rlang::list_len(3)
debug(rlang::list_len)
my_fun()
debugging in: rlang::list_len(3)
debug: {
    signal_soft_deprecated(paste_line("`list_len()` is soft-deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0.", 
        "Please use `new_list()` instead"))
    new_list(.n)
}
Browse[2]> sys.calls()
[[1]]
my_fun()

[[2]]
rlang::list_len(3)
```